# Different results reading text file from Eclipse local server and Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, character-encoding, bufferedreader

From GWT I read a text file "myFile.txt" as per below. The issue is that I get different results in the "input" string depending on the server:

- If I run in from Eclipse Indigo local server (debugging), "input" includes at the end characters "\r" and "\n".
- If I run it from Google App Engine, "input" includes at the end character "\n" only, so one character less in input.length.

Why does this happen, and how can I have the same behaviour?

Thanks

```
String input=readFromFile("myFile.txt");

public String readFromFile(String fileName) {
  File file = new File(fileName);
  StringBuffer contents = new StringBuffer();
  BufferedReader reader = null;
  try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String text = null;
    while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    contents.append(text).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
    try {
      if (reader != null) {
        reader.close();
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  contents.deleteCharAt(contents.length()-2); // Remove to make it work in GAE
  contents.deleteCharAt(contents.length()-1);
  return contents.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because line separators are different on different OSes. This is what [`System.getProperty("line.separator")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.htmlhttp://) does.

On Windows it's `\r\n\` (two chars), while on Linux it's `\n` (one char). [See here.](http://techcreeze.blogspot.com/2009/03/new-line-character-in-java-for-windows.html).